# Extract data distributed equally from a dataframe - R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame (df) with different number of rows (numElement) and I wish to extract from it X elements (numExtract) distributed equally  in the df and store them in the new dataframe (extractData).  When I use the script below sometimes I get in the extractData different number of element (bigger by one from the numExtract). How can I fix it?

Script:

```
numElement<-400
df<-data.frame(seq(1:numElement))

numExtract<-5
extractData <- df[seq(1, nrow(df), by = round(nrow(df)/numExtract)),]


numElement<-400
df<-data.frame(seq(1:numElement))

numExtract<-7

extractData <- df[seq(1, nrow(df), by = round(nrow(df)/numExtract)),]
```

Comment: Are you getting different results in each run?

Comment: No, the results are similiar

Comment: Using `by` without `round`?. It'll ensure the `extractData` to have same number of elements as in `numElement`

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment yet but `round` without extra arguments rounds the number to the nearest integer.

In your first case you want every 80th element and then in the second case every 57th element and that means you'll get the elements with indexes of `1 58 115 172 229 286 343 400` (total 8 indexes here).

Answer (score 0):

**Custom function**

Use `cut` to obtain more intuitive intervals, and extract the breaks. It uses `gsubfn:strapply` for substring extraction

```
library(gsubfn)
myfun <- function(maxval, numbreaks) {
              require(gsubfn)
              x <- unique(cut(1:maxval, numbreaks-1))
              A <- sapply(x, function(Z) round(as.numeric(strapply(as.character(Z), "^[(](\\S+)[,]", perl=TRUE))))
              A <- c(A, maxval)
              return(A)
         }
```

**Output**

```
myfun(400, 5)
# 1 101 200 300 400

myfun(400, 7)
# 1  68 134 200 267 334 400
```

Comment: The distance between the elements are not the same (1 to 68 and 68 to 134). Can that be corrected? (Asking out of curiosity)

Comment: `series <- c(1,  68, 134, 200, 267, 334, 400)`; `diff(series)` `# [1] 67 66 66 67 67 66`; The intervals should really be spaced `66.6666` units apart, but the output needs to be a whole number.